# Error in popup when indicating an id to confirm an operation in recatjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, popup

I'm developing an application in React.JS

I need to show a popup to validate an operation.

The code:

```js
const App = () => {
  ...
  const body = () => {
    return (
      item &&
      item.map((elem, j) => {
        return (
          <tr key={elem.id}>
            <td>
              <span>{elem.cat}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Warning!</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>Warning!</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                  <Button onClick={() => remove(elem.id)}>Delete</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
              <span onClick={handleShow}>
                <span>Delete</span>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span>Category</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{body()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It happens that the popup is taking the last `id` of the table as ordered, but I need it to be the one that corresponds to that row.

Comment: Instead of having Modal for each row, create separate Modal component and pass clicked row's id to modal and display it.

Comment: Yes I did and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551465/14678573 I have managed to solve the problem.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = (selected) => {
  setSelected(selected);
  setShow(true);
  };
```